# Can this Ruby error be caught with NeoVim/ALE/RuboCop/Syntastic?

Tags: ruby, neovim, rubocop, linter

I'm new to Ruby and doing some experimenting with NeoVim/ALE which I'm also new to. I'm coming from Perl using the syntastic plugin and I'm trying to figure out how to best set up NeoVim/ALE/RuboCop. I've never used a delinter before.

My confusion stems from this bit of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

r = Array() # Improper array initialization, should be Array.new()
puts r
```

When run, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from /Users/me/ruby/workshop/dink.rb:3:in `<main>'  
/Users/me/ruby/workshop/dink.rb:3:in `Array': wrong number of arguments (given  
0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
```

RuboCop didn't catch this error. I turned syntastic on and it didn't catch the error either. I assume because it's a runtime error and not a compile time error like I thought it would be. Running `ruby -c` on the script yields no errors either. But perhaps I'm wrong and aren't using the syntax checking tools properly. Can someone please confirm that this is indeed a runtime error and that it's impossible to catch before executing the script?

I have a second question as well: Do I need syntastic with Ruby? Does it do anything more that RuboCop doesn't?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both tools are correct, because there is the [`Array()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) method defined in `Kernel`.

That means this is not a syntax but a runtime error because that method expects at least one argument.

From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Array):

> `Array(arg) → array`
> Returns `arg` as an `Array`.
>
> First tries to call `to_ary` on `arg`, then `to_a`. If `arg` does not respond to `to_ary` or `to_a`, returns an `Array` of length 1 containing `arg`.

Comment: (though no tools would behave differently if the Array method did not exist -- it still _could_ exist)

Comment: Do I need syntastic at all? Does it do anything RuboCop doesn't?

Comment: What Do you mean by `syntastic`? Is that a gem you are using?

Comment: It's s vim plugin that does syntax checking. I just found this comment that may shed some light on things for me: "In languages with a managed runtime such as ruby where you don't really have the same kind of compile-time checking, a good linter is even more important." It seems that it's tougher to catch compile time errors with Ruby. With Perl, it was pretty obvious which errors were compile time and which were run time.

Comment: `my $r = Array()`, `my $r = Array.new()`, and `my $r = one array please, good sir` all `perl -c` as OK for me... I don't think Ruby's unique in having a flexible syntax where many spellings have _some_ meaning, even if it's not the one you intended.

Comment: The first one fails because it's a runtime error, no subroutine called "Array". The second and third examples fail when `use strict;` is turned on, which it always should be with Perl.

Comment: @StevieD: When you are interested in checking syntax then yes, you will need both. Because Rubocop isn't primarily a tool to check syntax but a tool to ensure that certain the code follows defined coding conventions or a code style guide your team agreed on.